# App facebook return error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I must use php-sdk and js-sdk. All have cookie:true. When the aplication isn't running for the world. I can login but every now and then,  I see: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." When the aplication is active nobody can't login. Of course, all users see "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." every second / third reload. I don't understand how working the "token" on Facebook.

In the examples I see:

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken()
```

But how use it?

My code (This is before head):

```
  require_once("src/facebook.php");

  $config = array(
      'appId' => 'XXXXXX',
      'secret' => 'XXXXX',
      'cookie' => TRUE,
  );
  $facebook   = new Facebook($config);
  $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
  if ($fbuser) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }

    $user_fbid  = $fbuser;
    $user_email = $user_profile["email"];
    $user_fnmae = $user_profile["first_name"];
   }
```

Js (in the head)

```
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
            appId      : 'XXX', // replace your app id here
            channelUrl : 'http://XXXX/', 
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true, 
            xfbml      : true  
            });
        };
        (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
```

Maybe I should send token, when the page is loaded? But how?

Thx :)

Comment: There’s hardly ever any need to call `getAccessToken` at all, the PHP is normally perfectly able to handle that internally. And where/how are you doing login, i don’t see that anywhere in your code …?

Comment: Because I didn't add mysql query... After $user_fnmae is create record to mysql.

Comment: I am talking about Facebook login, that connects the user to your app – that has nothing to do with your MySQL queries.